# how to find contribution of feature in accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, prediction, accuracy

Given a set of features, how do I find what all features are contributing how much to the accuracy / prediction ?

Answer (score 2):

When using one of the gold standards, the maximum likelihood, we have an ideal optimality criterion and associated proper accuracy scoring rule (deviance/log likelihood/measures derived from these such as $R^2$).  This means that you have available

1. The combined influence of all predictors, from for example the model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic
2. Partial contributions of predictors such as partial likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test statistics or approximations of them such as partial Wald tests (in the simplest case the square of a single regression coefficient divided by the square of its standard error).  Partial $R^2$ can be derived from these.

One nice and fast way to present things while allowing for combination of multiple terms per predictor is the proportion of $\chi^2$ explained by each predictor.  See [Relative importance of variables in Cox regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175111/relative-importance-of-variables-in-cox-regression) and the comment about bootstrapping ranks of predictors, which exposes the true difficulty of this task.