# How to assess the true significance of predictors in the face of collinearity and noisy features?

Tags: interpretation, multicollinearity, noise

In most practical cases, models are burdened with collinear and noisy features.  while regularization helps avoid overfitting by effectively simplifying the model, the question of interpretation of the relative importance of predictors in the "real world" remains.  How can we tackle this issue?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202277/what-are-variable-importance-rankings-useful-for