# Should partial $R^2$ add up to total $R^2$ in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

Following is a model created from `mtcars` dataset:

```
> ols(mpg~wt+am+qsec, mtcars)

Linear Regression Model

ols(formula = mpg ~ wt + am + qsec, data = mtcars)

                Model Likelihood     Discrimination    
                   Ratio Test           Indexes        
Obs       32    LR chi2     60.64    R2       0.850    
sigma 2.4588    d.f.            3    R2 adj   0.834    
d.f.      28    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        6.456    

Residuals

    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4811 -1.5555 -0.7257  1.4110  4.6610 

          Coef    S.E.   t     Pr(>|t|)
Intercept  9.6178 6.9596  1.38 0.1779  
wt        -3.9165 0.7112 -5.51 <0.0001 
am         2.9358 1.4109  2.08 0.0467  
qsec       1.2259 0.2887  4.25 0.0002
```

The model seems good with total $R^2$ of 0.85. However, partial $R^2$ values seen on following plot do not add up to this value. They add up to approx 0.28.

```
> plot(anova(mod), what='partial R2')
```

[image]

Is there any relation between sum of all partial $R^2$ and total $R^2$ ?  The analysis is done with `rms` package.

Comment: (In addition to the very good answer by amoeba) A close question about standardized regression coefficient vs partial correlation http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76815/3277.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### No.

One way to understand partial $R^2$ for a given predictor is that it equals the $R^2$ that you would get if you first regress your independent variable on *all other predictors*, take the residuals, and regress those on the remaining predictor.

So if e.g. all predictors are perfectly identical (collinear), one can have decent $R^2$, but partial $R^2$ for all predictors will be exactly zero, because any single predictor has zero additional explanatory power.

On the other hand, if all predictors together explain the dependent variable perfectly, i.e. $R^2=1$, then partial $R^2$ for each predictor will be $1$ too, because whatever is unexplained by all other predictors can be perfectly explained by the remaining one.

So the sum of all partial $R^2$ can easily be below or above the total $R^2$. They do not have to coincide even if all predictors are orthogonal. Partial $R^2$ is a bit of a weird measure.

See this long thread for many more details: [Importance of predictors in multiple regression: Partial $R^2$ vs. standardized coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64010).

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation. This could be happening in the situation in this question also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155447/can-partial-r2-change-so-much-if-r2-remains-same . Then is partial R^2 a reasonable indicator of importance or contribution of individual predictors? Or would you suggest something else like 'proportion R^2' or 'remaining R^2' or 'chisq' or 'chisq minus df' or 'proportion chisq' or 'aic'? All of these are available in rms package. Or standardized coefficients?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure why that question was put on hold as unclear; I think it is clear (and is almost a duplicate of this one but arguably not quite). Regarding reasonable indicators of importance of predictors: I strongly invite you to read the thread I linked to in my answer, which is *precisely* about this question. There is my own answer there as well, where I make a brief overview of several various indicators. They all have various shortcomings; it seems that there is no (and cannot be a) perfect solution to this problem.

Comment: I put it on hold as unclear because no explanation *at all* was given of how the two models differed. Perhaps I was wrong in thinking an answer was wanted for that specific situation. Given *this* answer, do either of you think it needs re-opening?

Comment: So partial R2 are comparable within one graph and not between 2 graphs. Also 'partial R2' does not really indicate the contribution to total R2 and hence I think it is a misnomer. There is no need for other question now since I have got the answer here.

Comment: I have been upvoting all answers. Even then I have accepted vast majority of my questions.

Comment: @rnso: Oh, great, thanks. That might have been the biggest mass acceptance in the history of CrossValidated :-)