# How to interpret a partial r statistic?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interpretation, partial-correlation

I am not sure how to interpret a partial r statistic in a research paper I am reading for my class. I’ve attached a photo of the table provided by the researchers but cannot figure it out. I’m not sure how to interpret these as strong or weak, nor do so know how they affect the implicit understanding of the rest of the data presented. I’ve spent hours researching this and find myself growing more and more confused. I need someone to explain this is plain language to me.

[image: img]

Comment: Hi, does [this reply](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155497/should-partial-r2-add-up-to-total-r2-in-multiple-regression/) by amoeba help you?

Answer (score 1):

The partial r value for each predictor variable represents the correlation between that individual variable and the outcome variable, if the effects of all other predictors were removed.

For example, say I had a multiple regression of anxiety, depression, and tiredness (all continuous data) predicting scores on a math test. The partial r for anxiety would be saying, "What is the relationship between anxiety and test score, when I control for the effects of depression and tiredness?". It is an attempt to isolate a relationship from the other variables.