# SPSS - Automatic Linear Modeling "Importance" Numbers

Tags: regression, spss, linear, importance

I have a large set of survey data. I'm looking at trying to find out which variables are the most *important* to impacting a DV (call it "happiness"). I'm not looking to find a beta number like a typical regression. I theorize that some of my ~14 variables will have co-linearity. Is it appropriate to do the following in SPSS, and am I interpreting this correctly?

Analyze->Regression->Automatic Linear Modeling
Predictors = all my ~14 variables
Target = my DV ("happiness)

Build options - automatically prepare data OFF
Model selection = forward stepwise
Criteria for entry/removal = F Statistics, including effects with p-values less than 0.05 and removing p-values greater than .1.

Hit Run.

Scroll down in the model to "coefficients, and expand window.

Variable 1 - coefficient .16, sig .000, importance .52
Variable 2 - coefficient .10, sig .000, importance .19
Variable 3 - coefficient .07, sig .000 importance .16
Variable 4 - coefficient .06, sig .000, importance .08
Variable 5 - coefficient .06, sig .001, importance .05

The coefficient I assume is beta - i.e. if this variable increased by 1, "happiness" should increase by the coefficient #. Now, what I'm really interested in is the importance #. **Am I correct in interpreting this for variable 1 as, "Our model suggests 52% of the variance of happiness is due to this variable."**

Further, am I correct that in that this modeling indeed removes colinearity from variables? Or do I need to do that in a different way. I'm hopeful SPSS is essentially doing a "relative weights analysis" here.

Thanks, and hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

SPSS Help or Algorithms document somewhere states about the "variable impotrance" in the Automatic Linear Modeling procedure:

> For linear models, the importance of a predictor is the residual sum
> of squares with the predictor removed from the model, normalized so
> that the importance values sum to 1. This is the leave-one-out method
> to compute the predictor importance, based on the residual sum of
> squares *SSe* by removing one predictor at a time from the final full
> model.

So, variable (predictor) importance (VI)

```
VI = SSE_without_the_predictor - SSE_full_model, and the
Normalized_VI = VI / Sum(VI)_of_all_the_predictors.
```

But note that

```
(SSE_without_the_predictor - SSE_full_model) / SSY
```

is the **squared part correlation** of the predictor with Y. Since SSY (Sum of squares in centered Y) is constant here, it does not influence the normalized VI.

Thus, the normalized VI of a predictor is nothing else than the relative size, among all the predictors, of its squared part correlation with Y.

---

See @amoeba's [overview](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144344/3277) of various "importance" measures in regression setting. Check also other posts tagged [importance].

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response! Much appreciated. I apologize because I'm not super stats-y so this is a bit out of my element. Can you explain how this result generated by SPSS is different from a typical relative weights analysis (ex. https://www.statisticshowto.com/relative-weights/). 

I'm confused on your last sentence. If I'm understanding you correctly (and I may not be), wouldn't importance be related to the coefficient? However, they vary at diffe levels - i.e. coefficient .16 for variable 1, importance of .52; coefficient of .10 for v2, importance of .19; but, .16 is not 2.7x .10.